# Imprimir array al reves

Tags: java

Tengo este codigo el cual me imprime de derecha a izquierda poco a poco como si fuera un cartel electronico.
Necesito que se imprima de izquierda a derecha
Este es el codigo

```
 char []desplazado=new char[10];
 String texto="Mira cómo mola esto, una marquesina";
 for (int i = 0; i < desplazado.length; i++) {
     desplazado[i]+=texto.charAt(i);
     System.out.println(desplazado);
 }
```

Comment: ¿Puedes aclarar si lo que quieres es que se imprima únicamente al revés pero manteniendo el orden del array original? Estaría bien que pongas un ejemplo de como te lo imprime y como esperas tu que lo imprima.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente: crear una función que, dado un paramétro String `text` y un parámetro entero `index`, te devuelva hasta 10 caracteres de `text` desde la posición `index`:

```
String subcadena(String text, int index) {
    int longitud = text.length();
    if (index + 10 > longitud) {
      return text.substring(index); //hasta el final
    }
    return text.substring(index,index + 10);
}
```

Y ahora puedes hacer algo similar a lo que tenías antes:

```
String texto = "Mira cómo mola esto, una marquesina";
for (int i = texto.length - 1;i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(subcadena(texto, i));
}
```

Te pongo el equivalente en Javascript, para que lo veas funcionar:

```js
function subcadena(text,index) {
  let longitud = text.length;
  let resultado;
  if (index + 10 > longitud) {
    return text.substring(index); //hasta el final
  } 
  return text.substring(index, index + 10);
}

const texto="Mira cómo mola esto, una marquesina";
let time=0
for (let i= texto.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector('#marquesina').innerHTML = subcadena(texto, i);
  }, time*100);
  time++;
}
```

```html
<p id="marquesina"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el for por `for (int i = desplazado.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: Eso no haría que se imprima al revés, Si no que lo rellenaría al revés.

Comment: No me ha imprimido al reves